# mysql select Multiple groups multiple where

Tags: mysql

i have a table stores activity 
a want to generate a overview selecting sum(total) based on the date (unixtime)

like Select SUM(total) from list where date between 123456789 and 2000000 
somethings like this ..

but i would like to get more date ranges out with one query

to have a listable result like

- sum(total) of 2 days ago
- sum(total) of yesterday
- sum(total) of today

and so on ...

Comment: you can UNION multiple queries together if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `UNION`. Something like this should work:

```
select SUM(total) as Total,
    SUM(
        case when date >= DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
            and date < DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY) then total end
    ) TwoDaysAgoTotal,
    SUM(
        case when date >= DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
            and date < CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00') then total end
    ) as OneDayAgoTotal,
    SUM(
        case when date >= CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00') then total end
    ) as TodayTotal
from list
where date between 123456789 and 2000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Union statement don't solve your case? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/pt/union.html

Comment: union does it actually . but its Really slow (at this moment i do fetch 16 Days of History with SUM() and where selecting the dates (its in unixtime (not sql date)) using 16 Select's .. much faster than a union .... but this is really Bad code i think. i guess the performance comes because the dates are stored as integers instead of SQL Dates